# HTML modified jQuery listener

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, listener, handler

I have created a chatbox in jQuery / MySQL and PHP.
To display new messages, I refresh the #chatcontent  on my page using a POST HTTP request and the `$('#chatcontent').html(data)` method.
My problem is that the DOMSubtreeModified listener will detect a change even when there are no new messages because I refresh the content each second.

So how can I detect that there actually is a new message ?

Comment: How are messages being loaded?

Comment: jQuery requests all the entries in the database using a PHP script which displays all the content, then jQuery catches all the data and `.html(data)` it in my #chatcontent <div>

Comment: really not hard to keep track of last id received and compare

Comment: how would you do it ? where should I "display" my id ?

Comment: Since you are doing this all with html from server just add attributes to each `message` container or element. Would be a lot more efficient if you didn't reload every time and send that id and only return new data if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal setup for this type of problem would be send data from server to client using websockets. Just listen for the new messages on server and send it to the client using websocket.

If you do not want to use websocket, do a AJAX polling lets say every 3 seconds and pass the ID of last received message. Update the innerHTML of DIV only if you have received some JSON data. Try not sending HTML content from the server.